# Strange behaviour on safari in Iphone when opening custom created .ics file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, icalendar

I'm creating custom .ics file with javascript. when I try to open it in my desktop it works good, but when I open it with with safari on my Iphone it has a weird behaviour in which it open a new screen to add the event to calendar, but it is closed immediately.
See video: https://vimeo.com/267547030

This is the code:

HTML:

```
<a id="test">Demo</a>
```

JS:

```
  var icsMSG = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" +
"VERSION:2.0\n" +
"PRODID:-//www.marudot.com//iCal Event Maker\n" +
"CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\n" +
"BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\n" +
"TZID:Asia/Damascus\n" +
"TZURL:http://tzurl.org/zoneinfo-outlook/Asia/Damascus\n" +
"X-LIC-LOCATION:Asia/Damascus\n" +
"BEGIN:STANDARD\n" +
"TZOFFSETFROM:+0300\n" +
"TZOFFSETTO:+0200\n" +
"TZNAME:EET\n" +
"DTSTART:19701030T000000\n" +
"RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1FR\n" +
"END:STANDARD\n" +
"BEGIN:DAYLIGHT\n" +
"TZOFFSETFROM:+0200\n" +
"TZOFFSETTO:+0300\n" +
"TZNAME:EEST\n" +
"DTSTART:19700327T000000\n" +
"RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1FR\n" +
"END:DAYLIGHT\n" +
"END:VTIMEZONE\n" +
"BEGIN:VEVENT\n" +
"DTSTAMP:20180502T071600Z\n" +
"UID:20180502T071600Z-1723765681@marudot.com\n" +
"DTSTART;TZID=\"Asia/Damascus\":20180509T120000\n" +
"DTEND;TZID=\"Asia/Damascus\":20180510T120000\n" +
"SUMMARY:scaxczads\n" +
"END:VEVENT";

  $('#test').click(function () {
    window.open( "data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG));
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried using a third-party tool to generate the .ics file, and compare if it is the same to the one you have? https://apps.marudot.com/ical/

Comment: Do you need the `escape()`?

Comment: Update: I've tested your code in a JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/qbnkd473/2/, and testing all the way down to iOS7 Safari on BrowserStack, and it still works. I can see, however, that your ICS string is missing a trailing `END:VCALENDAR` at the very end. Would that fix your issue if you add it?

Comment: @Terry This is exactly what I did. I copy pasted the content of the .ics file to my js. I try to add what you said and it still does not work. Although, After testing it multiple times, it sometimes works perfectly and sometimes does the behaviour as in the video I send. When I'm using the website you mentioned about and download an ics file from there, it always works so I'm really not sure what an I missing here

Comment: @Terry same behaviour on the fiddle you send. see: https://vimeo.com/267556152 The strange thing is that when I'm downloading the file from apps.marudot.com/ical it doesn't ask me to allow calendar invite.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue? We can observe the same behaviour on our generated ics files. Sometime it works, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

I am using library: [Datebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxr8F.png)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxr8F.png): https://www.npmjs.com/package/datebookfor generating **.ics** files from custom data. Also supports Google Calendar, Yahoo Calendar, Outlook Calendar.

**escape()** is deprecated now, you should be using **encodeURI()** instead.

iCal scenario:

- For large devices browser, I download the **.ics** file I am using:

  ```
     const icalendar = new ICalendar(this.config);
     icalendar.download();
  ```

This downloads the .ics file and when you open it you can add it to the default calendar.

- For mobile devices browser I am using

  ```
     const icalendar = new ICalendar(this.config);
     window.open('data:text/calendar;charset=utf8,' + encodeURI(icalendar.render()));
  ```

**icalendar.render()** generates .ics file and it looks like this:[image: ics string]